# Why second statement is printing hex value

Tags: c++

The c++ code using stream operators is failing. I'm not able to figure out why the second print "DEF" is not working::

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
struct logger :public std::ostringstream {};

struct logger_flush {};

logger_flush endl;

std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const logger_flush& lf) {
    logger& oss = dynamic_cast<logger&>(os);
    std::cout << oss.str() << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    logger() << 100 << "ABC?" << endl;
    logger() << "DEF" << endl;
}
```

Output is:

100ABC?

0x40168d

Comment: Seems to work with gcc. http://ideone.com/XylUCx

Comment: Does not even compile for me. You aren't returning anything in your operator<< function.

Comment: @user1052842 - this should be a warning, I think.

Answer (score 3):

`logger()` is an rvalue, which is why the `::operator<<(logger(), "DEF")` call you want does not work: that overload of `operator<<` takes an lvalue reference parameter, and rvalues cannot bind to non-const lvalue references.

However, rvalue classes do allow methods to be called, so overload `logger().operator<<((void*)"DEF")` is available, and it becomes the best match for `logger() << "DEF"`.

It works for `logger() << 100 << "ABC?" << endl;` because `logger() << 100` returns an lvalue reference, and that lvalue reference is then a valid argument for `::operator<<`.

Answer (score 3):

This should work in C++11 because of the `ostream& operator<<(ostream&& os, const T& value)` overload, which allows you to use streams as rvalues.

In C++03 it will print an address because the `void*` overload is a member (which can be called on rvalues) whereas the `char const*` overload is a non-member, and the first parameter is an `ostream&`, which cannot be bound to rvalues.

Comment: It doesn't work with clang 3.3 on my computer. The lack of a return statement in the overloaded `operator<<` is undefined behavior, and this UB eventually resulted in signal EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION being raised. Fortunately, the response to this UB was not invoke the `erase_hard_drive()` function.

Comment: @DavidHammen barring the undefined behaviour it will work. My answer is mostly about why the `void*` overload is chosen over the `char const*` one.

Comment: After fixing the UB problem, I get the same output for -std=c++03 and -std=c++11 using clang++ (clang release 3.3).

Comment: @DavidHammen then clang 3.3 must have an incomplete standard library implementation.